# In Maven, How does one replace a file in the output configuration directory only if the source file exists

Tags: maven

I have seen documentation of `copy-rename-maven-plugin` to add a file copy to a maven build but I have not seen how to execute it only if a given path exists (either the source file or the source directory).   My use-case is that I would like to modify configuation files in my local dev environment but not have those files in source control.

Comment: Why do you need that plugin? What is the purpose in your case? Please describe your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use profiles in Maven project:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <exists>path-to-four-file</exists>
      </file>
    </activation>
    
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
.... your plugin here ...
        </plugin>
      </plugins> 
    <build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```